# Vue.js - ref attribute remove automatically from input

Tags: forms, vue.js, attributes, vue-validator

For use confirmed validation in vue-validate, I set :ref for my inputs.
But after rendering template, ref attr removed from inputs and confirmed validation send false.

```
 <ValidationProvider :rules="field.rules">
            <div slot-scope="{ errors, classes }">
                <input :id="field.model" :name="field.model" :ref="field.model"
                       :type="field.inputType" :value="value" v-on:input="$emit('update:value', $event.target.value)"
                       :class="classes" class="form-control">
                <Errors :errors="errors"></Errors>
            </div>
        </ValidationProvider>
```

Comment: The `ref` attribute won't be in the DOM if that's what you mean. That's perfectly normal, as with most of the special Vue attributes it is interpreted by Vue and doesn't get added to the DOM nodes.

Comment: No, I mean ref attr not work at all. vue must use that for confirmed validation, but its not work

Comment: It should work. Can you show the value of the `field` variable?

Comment: field is an object. has detail of one field. field.model in this example equal to "password"